# Flatten directory with incrementing names

Tags: bash, scripts, directory

I need a bash script for flattening a directory with same names, and get an ordered output after a conversion.

input folder structure:

```
/in1/file1.wav
/in1/file2.wav
/in1/file3.wav

/in2/file1.wav
/in2/file2.wav
/in2/file3.wav
/in2/file4.wav

/in3/file1.wav
/in3/file2.wav
```

and I need an output directory like this:

```
/out/file0001.mp3
/out/file0002.mp3
/out/file0003.mp3
/out/file0004.mp3
/out/file0005.mp3
/out/file0006.mp3
/out/file0007.mp3
/out/file0008.mp3
/out/file0009.mp3
```

where `/out/file004.mp3` is the mp3 conversion of `/in2/file1.wav`

I've done some trials with `find -exec` but I can't get it to work

(don't worry about conversion, I just use `ffmpeg -i fileinput fileoutput.mp3`)

Comment: You need leading zeros?

Comment: yes, i absolutly need them!

Answer (score 1):

ok, i understand that shell scripting is a really power tool but it is real mess:

i have tried with [thefourtheye](https://askubuntu.com/users/147253/thefourtheye) [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/291025/13861) but the `sort` command messed everything up because of the order was like this:

```
Sequence 1.wav
Sequence 10.wav
Sequence 11.wav
Sequence 12.wav
Sequence 2.wav
Sequence 3.wav
Sequence 4.wav
...
```

and the spaces was a problem so i had to add `"` but there was some mess too i don't remember exactly where, then i tried to put some debug print and it didn't work so...
In the end I tested it on a Mac OS/X terminal and it has another shell i never heard about (zsh) that uses different commands.. a big mess.

I came up with a small python script. Maybe it is dirty but it works:

```
import os, sys

count = 1
for dirpath, diname, filenames in os.walk('.'):

    if dirpath=='.' or dirpath=='./out':
        continue

    filenames = [f for f in filenames if f.split('.')[1]=='aif' and f[0]!='.']
    filenames = sorted(filenames, key=lambda f: int(f.split('.')[0].split(' ')[1]))

    for f in filenames:
        filepath = dirpath+'/'+f
        ffmpeg_command = 'ffmpeg -i "'+filepath+'" out/track'+"%04d" % (count,)+'.mp3'
        count += 1
        print ffmpeg_command
        os.system(ffmpeg_command)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's roughly how I would do it. Iterate the directories in the right order, then the files. It assumes there's no dir higher than `in9/` and no file higher than `file99.wav` . If there are, extend the loops accordingly. E.g. `for dir in in[0-9]/ in[1-9][0-9]/; do`

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0
for dir in in[0-9]/; do
    for file in "$dir"/file[0-9].wav "$dir"/file[1-9][0-9].wav; do
        printf -v dest 'out/file%04d.mp3' "$((++i))"
        ffmpeg -i "$file" "$dest"
    done
done
```